# Xamarin.Forms Errors (ADB0000:Value Cannot be null)

Tags: c#, xamarin

What does this even mean? I had my program running and deploying fine and then the next day this error popped up?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Tool
>   Error     ADB0000: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2    at
>   System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidTools.PlatformPackage.GetVersionInfo(String
>   frameworkVersion)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidTools.PlatformPackage.GetPlatformPackageVersion(Int32
>   apiLevel, String& packageName)    at
>   AndroidDeviceExtensions.d__33.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at AndroidDeviceExtensions.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__101.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__99.MoveNext()
>     0

I was trying to follow an online YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAZ4kPf5eTc) and it worked fine until I got this error?

Comment: Show the code that causes this error, also mentioned the values that you are having for those variables

Comment: Have you tried another device or AVD?

Comment: This started occasionally happening to me after I upgraded vs2017 from 15.7.6 to 15.8.9.  My solution was to simply deploy to my android device again, and then it worked.  I consider myself amply blessed because it's a minor issue for me - which certainly has not been the case when upgrading Visual Studio in the past.

On a related note, if you ever upgrade to a version of Visual Studio that's broken, I've found that (for me) it is easier to restore from a bare-metal backup than to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same issue. The fix for me was:
In Android emulator hold the app icon and move it to uninstall. Rebuild, deploy and run from VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Updating nuget fixed my problem. For me root cause was Xamarin forms was not working due to the older versions of xamarin dlls. I updated all the dlls and worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, Here is how i fix this error

1-Delete bin and obj folder from all projects.

2-clean and rebuild whole project.

3- Uninstall the app from emulator (device).

Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer settings and disable verify apps via USB. Then you can install .apk without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close VS
2. Delete bin directory
3. clean solution
4. Rebuild Solution